# Open source HTTP/HTTPS proxy

Tags: open-source, cross-platform, http, proxy

I'm looking for a multi-platform (Linux / Mac OS X / Windows 7), open source proxy, with following features:

- HTTPS support
- could forward to another remote proxy
- web sockets proxying
- able to add custom HTTP headers on the fly
- FTP proxying (optional)

Privoxy could be fine but it misses web sockets and FTP proxying.

Comment: What about Squid? I don't know if it answer all needs, but it is very good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org)

> mitmproxy is an interactive man-in-the-middle proxy for HTTP and HTTPS
>   with a console interface.

Features

- Intercept HTTP & HTTPS requests and responses and modify them on the fly
- Save complete HTTP conversations for later replay and analysis
- Replay the client-side of an HTTP conversations
- Replay HTTP responses of a previously recorded server
- TCP proxy
- Reverse proxy mode to forward traffic to a specified server
- Transparent proxy mode on OSX and Linux
- Make scripted changes to HTTP traffic using Python
- SSL/TLS certificates for interception are generated on the fly

Release builds are available at github for multiple platforms: https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/releases